# How to link a cell in workbook A to workbook B and another cell in workbook B with VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a new VBA learner. I would be appreciated if you help me with this problem:

I have two workbooks. On one of those, I have a userForm that all the information comes from that. comp is one of the data entry from that. By entering this information I want to create a new workbook with this name and also on the active sheet one cell get the same info. in this order, I've made this code so far. But I also want two more things that I don't know how to do it; first I want that cell in the active sheet to be linked with the new workbook. And second I need the cell right next to the previous one to get the same value as one specific cell in the new workbook ("h12").

```
Dim path As String

Dim filename1 As String

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\payam\Desktop\temp.xlsx")

path = "C:\Users\payam\Desktop\"

filename1 = comp.Text

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1 & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2") = comp.Text

ActiveWorkbook.Close

eRow = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Worksheets("Sheet7").Cells(eRow, 1).Value = comp.Text
```

Comment: You can  link with `Hyperlink` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add

Comment: Thank you for responding, but it works for a specific cell and did not work with my code. @ProfoundlyOblivious

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious I think I got it thanks for the hint! Could you pls tell me if linking a cell to another cell is the same method?!

Comment: Yes, you can use a `hyperlink` to another cell. The text displayed by a hyperlink is static by default, such that a hyperlink to a target cell does not update the displayed text when the target text changes, but it can be modified so that it does update the text.  The text source simply needs a normal worksheet function that points to the target.  It can be as simple as `=A1=B1`